# How to Convert a character array to string array

Tags: vb.net, .net-2.0, type-conversion, converters

I have the code below that requires me to convert a character array to string array, but I get the following error: `Option Strict On disallows implicit conversions from '1-dimensional array of Char' to 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable(Of String)'`

```
    Dim lst As New List(Of String)
    lst.AddRange(IO.Path.GetInvalidPathChars())
    lst.AddRange(IO.Path.GetInvalidFileNameChars())

    lst.Add("&")
    lst.Add("-")
    lst.Add(" ")

    Dim sbNewName As New StringBuilder(orignalName)
    For i As Integer = 0 To lst.Count - 1
        sbNewName.Replace(lst(i), "_")
    Next

    Return sbNewName.ToString
```

I tried using a converter through Array.ConvertAll, but couldn't find a good example, I could use a loop, but thought there would be a better way. Could anyone help?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just change the lst.AddRange lines to this:

```
Array.ForEach(Path.GetInvalidPathChars(), AddressOf lst.Add)
Array.ForEach(Path.GetInvalidFileNameChars(), AddressOf lst.Add)
```

Answer (score 1):

VB Linq syntax is not a strong point for me, but to get you started, consider selecting the items from the character arrays and converting each to string. In C#, that would be

```
lst.AddRange(System.IO.Path.GetInvalidPathChars().Select(c => c.ToString());
```

Thanks to NYSystemsAnalyst for the VB syntax

```
lst.AddRange(System.IO.Path.GetInvalidPathChars().Select(Function(c) c.ToString()))
```

Without Linq, you could simply iterate in a loop explicitly

```
For Each c as Char in System.IO.Path.GetInvalidPathChars()
    lst.Add(c.ToString())
Next c
```

Comment: This is also an option.  Here is the VB syntax:  lst.AddRange(Path.GetInvalidPathChars().Select(Function(c) c.ToString()))
        lst.AddRange(Path.GetInvalidFileNameChars().Select(Function(c) c.ToString()))

Comment: @MrShoubs, added non-Linq answer.